# Allowing the user to click on an image an a profile popup appears

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog

I'm working on an "about the team" page for a website.  I'd like to put the pictures of the 8 team members on the page, and when the user clicks on a picture, a profile should appear in a modal popup.

I'm aware of jQuery modal popups, but the main problem is that I need 8 different popups (one for each team member).  How would I do this - is there a plugin available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Dialog:
HTML:

```
<div id="profile-dialog" title="Member's profile"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#profile-dialog').html('Content for specific member');
$('#profile-dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
        'close': function() {
            $('#profile-dialog').dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the question you asked:

```
HTML Markup:

<body>
<img src="images/img.png/jpg/gif" alt="" width="" height="" id="image name"/>
<div id="image name-dialog" title="Description"></div> 

    *The id inside this div tag is very important. Always add -dialog tag to the image 
     name. this will be used by the java script to identify the image and append the 
     dialog box to it*.

    *Create as many HTML mark ups for the images you need the dialog for with the div 
     dialog tag as shown above*.


Java Script (insert this script before the </body> tag of your html page:

<script>
$('#image name-dialog').html('type content for dialog here');
$('#image name-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen:false / true,
    draggable:false /true,
    closeOnEscape:false /true,
    resizable:false /true,
    position:"left" "right",
    hide:{effect: "fade" / "pop"},
    show:{effect: "fade" / "pop"},
    width:00, (give a number, say, 500 / 400 etc)
     modal:true / false,

buttons: {
    'close': function() {
        $('#image name-dialog').dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
$( "#image name" ).click(function(){
    $( "#image name-dialog" ).dialog("open");
});

    * Add the same code with the appropriate / respective image id and image 
    description for the next image. Do this for all your images*

</script>
</body>
</html>

    Now save your html document, open the saved document in a browser and click on    
    the image. You will see a pop coming up on the page with the contents you want. In 
    the  java script you can change the position, size, effect, width etc to position 
    and size the dialog box as you want it to look. 

    This works. Worked for me smoothly. 


    You can post any content inside the dialog box. I haven't yet found out a solution 
    to add css styles to the dialog box yet.

    Hope this works for you. Coding gurus, please correct me if I am wrong. :)


    Regards
```